# Matrix-free definition for an operation on symmetric positive semidefinite bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, bilinear-form

Let $SPD_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of all symmetric and positive semidefinite bilinear forms $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Define a binary operation $(f,g) \mapsto f \ast g$ on $SPD_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as follows:

1. pick an orthonormal basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and represent $f, g$ as matrices $F, G$ w.r.t. $B$;
2. lef $f \ast g$ be the bilinear form associated with $F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}}$ w.r.t. $B$ (it is a symmetric and positive semidefinite form).

The above operation is well-defined because it does not depend on the choice of $B$ since, for any orthogonal matrix $P$ (a change from one orthonormal basis to another), we have

$$(P^{\top}F^{\frac{1}{2}}P)(P^{\top}GP)(P^{\top}F^{\frac{1}{2}}P) = P^{\top}(F^{\frac{1}{2}}GF^{\frac{1}{2}})P$$

Is it possible to define $f \ast g$ without reference to matrix representation?

The problem for me is that matrix multiplication does not correspond to an operation on bilinear forms via isomorphism with matrices (unlike the case of the isomorphism between linear maps and matrices).

Comment: As I commented on your previous question, this operation is either boring or basis-dependent. Suppose $g$ is positive-definite and choose a $g$-orthonormal basis. Then $G$ is the identity and $H = F$.

Comment: It is also strange to use "orthogonal bases" here, by which I assume you mean orthogonal with respect to the standard inner product, as this has nothing to do with the orthogonal bases of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff, what do you mean by $g$-orthonormal basis? You use this as it means the matrix representing $g$ w.r.t. such a basis is the identity.

Comment: Yes, that is what that means: a  basis which is orthonormal with respect to $g$, i.e. a basis $e_i$ such that $g(e_i, e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. This is **guaranteed** to exist when $g$ is symmetric positive-definite.